# laravel mysql display table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to display a table onto my web application which I built using laravel. Below is the laravel code in a controller I created.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB; 

class tableController extends Controller {


public function getTable()
{

  $test = DB::table('test')->get();

     return view('test.index', ['test' => $test]);
 }

// return "table goes here" ;

}
```

When I go to the web page, I get the following error :

> ErrorException in MySqlConnector.php line 35: Undefined index: charset

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Didi you configure your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if you connection in database.php file like this:

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',

            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'db',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

Comment: I was missing the charset in my database.php file and the mysql collation was not set to UTF8. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

in blade `{{$test}}` show all.

```
@foreach ($test as $val)
 {{$val}}  
@endforeach
```